# How do I change value of a property of type Driver<Bool> using a property of type Driver<Void>?

Tags: ios, observable, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift and I apologise how badly the question is framed but I couldn't find the proper terminology.

So basically I have a `let infoIconTapped: Driver<Void>` in one struct, and I have `let shouldShowInfoPopup: Driver<Bool>` in another struct.

What I want to do is I want to change the value of (or drive it) `shouldShowInfoPopup` to `true` or `false` using `infoIconTapped`. This should be done using `Driver` only which is my requirement.

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is toggle the visibility of the popup based on the tapping of the button. If so, then you need to maintain state and that means using the `.scan` operator.

```
func shouldShowInfoPopup(infoIconTapped: Driver<Void>) -> Driver<Bool> {
    return infoIconTapped
        .scan(false) { current, _ in !current }
        .startWith(false)
}
```

The above would be a free function (not in any class or struct) and could be used like this:

```
let showInfo = shouldShowInfoPopup(infoIconTapped: infoIconTapped)
```

If you *must* put the function in a class or struct, then put it in an extension on Driver itself like this:

```
extension SharedSequence where SharingStrategy == DriverSharingStrategy {
    var shouldShowInfoPopup: Driver<Bool> {
        scan(false) { current, _ in !current }
            .startWith(false)
    }
}
```

Which could be used like this:

```
let shouldShowInfoPopup = infoIconTapped.shouldShowInfoPopup
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your solution. However, when i try to assert `shouldShowInfoPopup` it's giving me error `nil` not equal to `false` in `XCTAssertEqual`.

Comment: Then you aren't using my solution. My solution has no optionals in it at all so there's no possible way for it to emit `nil`.

Comment: No No your solution saved me big time. I just was asserting with nil values. I had to pass Void in the coldObservable's events. THank you :)

Comment: In that case, you should accept the answer as correct.